# React Native - Components have unwanted white background on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm creating a cross platform application for android and iOS with React Native. Everything runs fine on Android, but for some reason the styling gets messed up on IOS Devices. There is an odd white border around some components, take a look:
[image]

Any one who had the same problem as me?

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.43.3

Comment: It might be caused because you are not specifying background color. Did you try it?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca I could do that (and it'd fix it) but I never had to do that before on React Native projects. Any idea why it wouldn't work now?

Comment: Not sure if it is caused by some changes on iOS or some changes made on ReactNative, but it seems that Android fill up with transparent by default while iOS doesn't. I will post the comment as an answer so It is useful for other devs as well.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca It doesn't seem to happen on new projects I make with React Native...

Comment: I'm not really sure why, but I faced the same problem, specifying backgroundColor was the solution, sometimes uninstalling and reinstalling the app solved the problem as well, sometimes did not.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca This doesn't look like a permanent solution for me. There should be a logical fix for this :/

Comment: It might be in ReactNative docs or in its repo...

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused because you are not specifying background color.
So try **adding background color**.

I'm not sure if it is caused by some changes on iOS or some changes made on ReactNative, but it seems that Android fill up with transparent by default while iOS doesn't.